# Intra-Query Parallelism Deadlock Resolution

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, parallelism

I want to know how SQL Server handles intra-query parallelism deadlocks, and whether it kills one of the threads involved in the deadlock?

Will there be a change in the result set when this deadlock occurs? Or this just affects performance?

Comment: [Today’s Annoyingly-Unwieldy Term: "Intra-Query Parallel Thread Deadlocks"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2008/09/24/todays-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks/) will help you understand. Normally, adding a proper index or running the query serially will solve the problem.

Comment: @Kin that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Will add some more details in answer tomorrow. This type of stuff comes more colourful from paul white :-)

Comment: @Kin Thank you for the response. In my case, I know how to resolve the bug with query tuning, however, I need to give an answer on how the deadlock is affecting the result-set currently.
I have seen the deadlock graph and there is no entry for the victim-list. I believe this tells none of the threads were killed. 
Not much information is available on this on the public domain that is why I asked this here.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the deadlock graph xml ?

Comment: @Kin sorry, I won't be able to share the graph as I am not allowed to. I just need to know how SQL resolves the deadlock. It would be great if you can share some info on this.
Thanks!